# How do I get to Riddler's second hostage in the Enigma Conundrum side mission?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I've rescued Riddler's first hostage from the courthouse, and gone to the location of the second hostage, outside the *Black Canary*.  However, I've search all over the building and can't find any doors or other entrances.  **How do I get in the building with the second hostage?**  Or do I have to go somewhere else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look for a green question mark on the wall. You should be able to walk up to it and break through the wall to reveal a door hidden behind it.

Comment: +1 this took me a long while to figure out, it's not at all obvious that you can break through the wall.

Answer (score 2):

The spot shows up on your mission quest long before you can actually click to get in, at least for me. I had to find about ten more trophies before the question mark showed up... And the question mark shows up on detective mode not in regular mode.

Answer (score 0):

You will see a green question mark spray painted on the brick wall next to the covered Riddler trophy next to the Black Canary.  If you walk up to the wall close enough, it will tell you to press A to inspect.  After you press A, Batman will knock on the wall, looking for a hollow part and will break through.  Then go through the door.

Answer (score -1):

If you walk up to the green question mark on the wall it will tell u to click a button to break the wall and go into a hidden door

Comment: This is almost word-for-word identical to the existing accepted answer. If you agree with that answer, you can upvote it once you get at least 15 reputation.